# Facing a problem when I am hitting npm run dev and npm run serve command

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, caching, compiler-errors

After install a fresh Vue cli project when I am hitting **npm run serve** command then it's showing this type on error

```
npm ERR! missing script: serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NaimBiswas\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-08T17_12_07_143Z-debug.log
```

Can anybody help me to came out

Comment: In your `package.json` file there are a list of scripts. According to the error, there seems to be no `serve` script. Check this.

Comment: You can also run `npm run` to list available commands.